# Jquery ajax send JSON object with value of array of JSON objects

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Note: I am using Ruby on Rails on backend.

I want to send following data using JQuery AJAX:

```
data = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {c: 1, d: 2}]

$.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'post', 
      data: {'events': data}
    })
```

but when I send data like this using JQuery, i get following data on my rails backend

```
{"events"=><ActionController::Parameters {"0"=>{"a"=>"1", "b"=>"2"}, "1"=>{"c"=>"1", "d"=>"2"}} permitted: false>
```

Why I am not getting data like following on my backend

```
{"events"=>[{"a"=>"1", "b"=>"2"}, {"c"=>"1", "d"=>"2"}]
```

Moreover, I have seen some answers where people are saying to serialize using JSON.stringify
like

```
data = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {c: 1, d: 2}]

$.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'post', 
      data: {'events': JSON.stringify(data)}
    })
```

but that sends `events` value as string which needs to deserialize on backend. I don't think it should be necessary to use JSON.stringify but if it is necessary what's the reason ?

Comment: What if you send the whole thing as a string? `data: JSON.stringify({'events': data});`?

Comment: Can you explain what the issue is with the way the params are sent? That nested hash is the way rails generally handles param arrays and you have not explained why this is a problem

Comment: @matthew-e-brown it gives params as {"{\"events\":"=>{"{\"a\":1,\"b\":2},{\"c\":1,\"d\":2}"=>{"}"=>nil}}

Comment: @engineersmnky I just don't know that is it good practice to send array from ajax to backend in this form ? is there any better way ?

Answer (score -1):

its just a wild guess but did you try to use jquery-Ajax´s 'dataType' option ?

```
data = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {c: 1, d: 2}]

$.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'post', 
      data: {events: data}
    })
```

on the ruby side you may have to decode the json-string properly

Comment: `dataType: 'json'` still gives ```{"events"=><ActionController::Parameters {"0"=>{"a"=>"1", "b"=>"2"}, "1"=>{"c"=>"1", "d"=>"2"}} permitted: false>```

because as per Jquery documentation, dataType property tells what you are expecting from the server back in response.